# How do I get the response time for a request with HttpServer

Tags: java

I have a java HttpServer which doesn't have any issues so far.
This is my code right now:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
        server.createContext("/", new IndexHandler());
        server.setExecutor(null);
        server.start();
    }

    static class IndexHandler implements HttpHandler {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
            String response = "test";
            t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
            OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
            os.write(response.getBytes());
            os.close();
            System.out.println(String.format("%s %s %d %d -", t.getRequestMethod(), t.getRequestURI(), t.getResponseCode(), response.length()));
        }
    }
}
```

The code logs the URI, status code, request method and response length. How do I compute the time taken from the start of a request to it closing? BTW I have studied the documentation and they don't have any internal implementation for this..

Comment: You can see in the right corner of the postman for response time. But in prod, we have a middle layer that sends the metric with response time.

Comment: Basically I wanna log it to the server-side console; I can obviously get the response time from the client browser of curl or whatever.

Comment: On the server, you have to check for middleware which will start before the processing and reach the same place after processing and you have to log there. I am working in scala and we have a specific metric middle layer that does the same thing. You can check in your library do they have something like that or build a simple middle layer by yourself.

Comment: Can you maybe post one snippet and try if it works?

Comment: Hi, Its in scala http4s. you can search with respect to what you are using.
```
   val middleware: HttpMiddleware[F] = {
      { service: HttpRoutes[F] =>
        metrics(service)
      } compose { service: HttpRoutes[F] =>
        hadoopLoggerMiddleware(service)
      } compose { service: HttpRoutes[F] =>
        kafkaTrafficForwarder(service)
      }
    }
```
metric is one kind of middleware.

Comment: Got it, can you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap your request with middleware and then you have to log the response time. we are using metric middleware to do the same. It depends upon the server you are using. we are using http4s, otherwise you have to write the custom middleware.

```
    val middleware: HttpMiddleware[F] = {
      { service: HttpRoutes[F] =>
        metrics(service)
      } compose { service: HttpRoutes[F] =>
        hadoopLoggerMiddleware(service)
      } compose { service: HttpRoutes[F] =>
        kafkaTrafficForwarder(service)
      }
    }
```